# Using switch statement in Fibonacci sequence

Tags: c

Im currently writing a program which calculates the fibonacci number of a given integer using recursion. I created my own function 'fibonacci' and made the program to run on loops as you can see in the code.

The program wants me to use switch statement to operate the menu (The menu is the one where the user gets two options of either choosing to find fibonacci or to exit the program), and I am stuck on how to use switch statement in order to use the menu.

Here is the code I wrote so far

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int fibonacci(int num);

 int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
 int choice;
 int num;
 int sequence;

 printf("1) Calculate Fibonacci\n");
 printf("2) Exit\n");
 scanf("%d", &choice);

 if (choice == 1) 
 {
   do 
   {
     printf("Input integer n :\n");
     scanf("%d", &num);

     if (num < 0) 
     {
       printf("n should be a positive integer (n >= 1). Retry\n");
     }
   } while (num < 0);
 }

 if (choice == 1 && num > 0) 
 {
   printf("Fibonacci sequence of %d terms\n", num);
```

Comment: `switch` on `choice`.

Comment: I suggest you get the code working properly without a `switch` statement first. You do not check the return value from `scanf` to see if you got an input. Instead you check uninitialised variables `choice` and `num` which are indeterminate when `scanf` fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie:

> "The switch statement is a multi-way decision that tests whether an expression matches one of a number of **constant integer values**, and branches accordingly."

So it should look similar to this:

```
while ((choice = getchar())!= EOF){
    switch (choice){
      case '1':
          // calculate Fibonacci sequence
          break;
      case '2':
          return 0;
    }
}
```

As one of the comments suggests, either initialize your local variables in the beginning or check the return value of your getchar() or scanf() calls, since values of uninitialized variables are indeterminate.

If you've just started studying C, I suggest that you read the book that I mentioned. It's relatively short and has lots of helpful examples.

Comment: I sure will. Thank you very much for explaining this doubt to me

Comment: @HelloWorld Please accept the answer if you have no more questions